# The previous published revision should be available for the visitors while the current revision is in needs review state

Tags: 7, workbench

I am using [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module for moderation on nodes. I notice that it creates revision of the nodes.

I have a node which is in live/publish state therefore it is available for the site visitors. Then when an editor edit that node, I programmatically put that node in needs review state and create a new revision for that node.

After that the site visitors are not able to access that node until its state change to publish.

I want that the new revision should be needs review state and the previous publish revision of the node should be available to site visitors.

The code which I am using for setting the state of the node is as following.

```
$node->status = 0;
$node->revision = 1;
node_save($node);
workbench_moderation_moderate($node, 'needs_review');
```

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel? You should configure it so that editors can create new drafts. Then on the node view page a local task tab 'New Draft' becomes available, and they can edit the published revision to create a new draft, whilst the published revision remains intact. And if you then want to you can move a newly saved draft to needs review through Rules (or Action). I don't see the need for any custom code when out of the box you can configure it to your exact use case.

Comment: I have a different use case therefore I am using custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Before the revisioning I loaded the original node first. Then first save the new revision and then save the original node.

My code now looks like this.

```
$original_node = node_load($nid);
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->revision = 1;
$node->workbench_moderation_state_new = 'needs_review';
node_save($node);
node_save($original_node);
```